# How can I tell which web server Zimbra 8.0.6 is running?

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, nginx, zimbra, jetty

This Zimbra installation was setup by personnel no longer here.

Before we proceed to update the suite to a current version, we're first trying to understand what/how it's doing, while lacking any notes or documentation.

I see Nginx and Jetty configuration folders, but it would be inappropriate to start editing them with this amount of uncertainty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zimbra 8 will run up to 3 webservers in parallel:

- Built-in Java webserver for Zimbra core
- Apache for spelling
- NgineX for Proxy

Only the first of those is essential, but a simple way to find what's listening on port 80 is to run:

```
netstat -anp | grep ':80'
```

It is important to understand, that there is no manual configuration involved: Zimbra's config daemon will take care of that.

I have had good experiences upgrading an orphaned 8.0 (installed by a fired engineer) to current 8.6 by exporting via Zextras migration tool ind importing via Zextras evaluation license.

Comment: That's certainly good news, but the upgrade is postponed for the moment. Is there some additional information I can provide to help come up with a  test for which software is running the webmail?

Comment: The webmail service is **definitly** served by the Java process. Simply run `netstat -anp | grep ':80'` to see, that port 80 is in use by the java app.

Comment: But let me stress, that I recommend rebuilding the machine and migrating the data: Chances are, that when the Zimbra installation is undocumented, that the OS installation is worse.